# scipy -- how to integrate a linearly interpolated function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function which is an interpolation of a relative large set of data. I use linear interpolation `interp1d` so there are a lot of non-smooth sharp point like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF1KM.png). The `quad` function from scipy will give warning because of the sharp points. I wonder how to do the integration without the warning?

Thank you!

---

Thanks for all the answers. Here I summarize the solutions in case some others run into the same problem:

1. Just like what @Stelios did, use `points` to avoid warnings and to get a more accurate result.
2. In practice the number of points are usually larger than the default limit(`limit=50`) of `quad`, so I choose `quad(f_interp, a, b, limit=2*p.shape[0], points=p)` to avoid all those warnings.
3. If `a` and `b` are not the same start or the end point of the data set `x`, the points `p` can be chosen by `p = x[where(x>=a and x<=b)]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you add full code so that others can help you more easily.

Comment: Are your original data points evenly spaced? In that case the integrated value is not much more than a scaled sum of your dataset.

Comment: Maybe smooth the function with a savitzky-golay filter before integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`quad` accepts an optional argument, called `points`. According to the documentation:

> points : (sequence of floats,ints), optional
>
> A sequence of break points in the bounded integration interval where
>   local difficulties of the integrand may occur (e.g., singularities,
>   discontinuities). The sequence does not have to be sorted.

In your case, the "difficult" `points` are exactly the x-coordinates of the data points. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import quad
np.random.seed(123)

# generate random data set 
x = np.arange(0,10)  
y = np.random.rand(10)

# construct a linear interpolation function of the data set 
f_interp = lambda xx: np.interp(xx, x, y)
```

Here is a plot of the data points and `f_interp`:
[image]

Now calling `quad` as

```
quad(f_interp,0,9)
```

return a series of warnings along with

> `(4.89770017785734, 1.3762838395159349e-05)`

If you provide the `points` argument, i.e.,

```
quad(f_interp,0,9, points = x)
```

it issues no warnings and the result is

> `(4.8977001778573435, 5.437539505167948e-14)`

which also implies a much greater accuracy of the result compared to the previous call.

Comment: Then if I want to integrate from 0.5 to 9, the points in x will be out of bound of the integrand, and the quad will return an error message. How should I do in this case? Thank you!

Comment: @ShuLiao In that case, you should provide the points in `x` that correspond in the interval `[0.5, 9]`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: The problem is I'm worried about the efficiency of doing something like `points=x[np.where(x>0.5)]` since this kind of integration will be done a lot of times in my code. So I'm curious about if there's other way to avoid this extra work..

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `interp1d`, you could use [`scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html).  That interpolator has the method `integral(a, b)` that computes the definite integral.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create some test data.
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 21)
np.random.seed(12345)
y = np.sin(1.5*x) + np.random.laplace(scale=0.35, size=len(x))**3

# Create the interpolator.  Use k=1 for linear interpolation.
finterp = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1)

# Create a finer mesh of points on which to compute the integral.
xx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 5*len(x))

# Use the interpolator to compute the integral from 0 to t for each
# t in xx.
qq = [finterp.integral(0, t) for t in xx]

# Plot stuff
p = plt.plot(x, y, '.', label='data')
plt.plot(x, y, '-', color=p[0].get_color(), label='linear interpolation')
plt.plot(xx, qq, label='integral of linear interpolation')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

The plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you! This does solve the integral of the function. But instead of the function it self, I also want to integrate this function multiply by other functions. For example, how to integrate the function `lambda x: x*finterp(x)[()]` without using `quad`?